# Best practices / most practical ways to implement mysqli connections

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, database-connection

I'm working on streamlining a bit our db helpers and utilities and I see that each of our functions such as for example `findAllUsers(){....}` or `findCustomerById($id) {...}` have their own connection details for example :

```php
function findAllUsers() {
    $srv = 'xx.xx.xx.xx';
    $usr = 'username';
    $pwd = 'password';
    $db = 'database';
    $port = 3306;
    $con = new mysqli($srv, $usr, $pwd, $db, $port);

    if ($con->connect_error) {
        die("Connection to DB failed: " . $con->connect_error);
    } else {
        sql = "SELECT * FROM customers..."
        .....
        .....
    }

}
```

and so on for each helper/function. SO I thought about using a function that returns the connection object such as :

```php
function dbConnection ($env = null) {
    $srv = 'xx.xx.xx.xx';
    $usr = 'username';
    $pwd = 'password';
    $db = 'database';
    $port = 3306;
    $con = new mysqli($srv, $usr, $pwd, $db, $port);

    if ($con->connect_error) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return $con;
    }
}
```

Then I could just do

```
function findAllUsers() {
    $con = dbConnection();
    if ($con === false) {
        echo "db connection error";
    } else {
        $sql = "SELECT ....
        ...
    }
```

Is there any advantages at using a function like this compared to a Class system such as `$con = new dbConnection()` ?

Comment: Both are just unacceptably bad.

Comment: Hey Common Sense, how are things? I knew the smell of overhead class usage would attract swiftly aha.
But is using a function for that bad as well though ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should open the connection only once. Once you realize that you only need to open the connection once, your function `dbConnection` becomes useless. You can instantiate the mysqli class at the start of your script and then pass it as an argument to all your functions/classes.

The connection is always the same three lines:

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$con = new mysqli($srv, $usr, $pwd, $db, $port);
$con->set_charset('utf8mb4');
```

Then simply pass it as an argument and do not perform any more checks with `if` statements.

```
function findAllUsers(\mysqli $con) {
    $sql = "SELECT ....";
    $stmt = $con->prepare($sql);
    /* ... */
}
```

It looks like your code was some sort of spaghetti code. I would therefore strongly recommend to rewrite it and use OOP with PSR-4.